# Plant identification?

Tags: identification, flowers

Can anyone identify this plant?  I bought a house and this is growing great as ground cover.  I would like to plant more if I can identify it.

If it helps, I live in Pennsylvania.  The flowers just opened now (late May/early June).  The plant is probably 3 feet tall.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Lychnis coronaria, a short lived, herbaceous perennial flowering plant. Likes moderately fertile, well drained soil and full sun, though it will tolerate some shade.